# swift collectionview add/remove cell when array changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, storyboard, listener

So what I basically want is to add a cell in a collectionview when the array gets bigger. But I do not know how I can do that. Do I have to add observers/listeners? And where do I put them exactly?

this function registers the cells (i am using nibs) this function is getting called in the viewDidLoad():

```
private func registerCells(){
       copmaniesInAreaCollection.register(UINib(nibName: "CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell")
        salonsInAreaCollection.register(UINib(nibName: "CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell")
    }
```

In this extension I am registering the cells based on how many barbers/salons there are and it works fine

```
extension HomePageController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        let defaultShowingCells = 1;
        
        switch collectionView {
        case copmaniesInAreaCollection:
            if barbers.count > 0{
                return barbers.count
            }
            return defaultShowingCells
        case salonsInAreaCollection:
            if salons.count > 0{
                return salons.count
            }
            return defaultShowingCells
        default: return defaultShowingCells
        }
    }
    
    

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let defaultCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NothingInAreaCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NothingInAreaCollectionViewCell
        
        let companyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CompanyPortraitCollectionViewCell
        
        switch collectionView{
        case copmaniesInAreaCollection:
            if barbers.count > 0{
                companyCell.setup(company: barbers[indexPath.row ])
                return companyCell
            } else {
                return defaultCell
            }
        case salonsInAreaCollection:
            if salons.count > 0{
                companyCell.setup(company: salons[indexPath.row ])
                return companyCell
            } else {
                return defaultCell
            }
        default: return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let controller = CompanyDetailViewController.instantiate()
        controller.company = collectionView == copmaniesInAreaCollection ? barbers[indexPath.row] : salons[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

So when I am trying to add a model to the barber array I want there to automatically come  another cell

this is the array:

```
var barbers: [Company] = []
```

this is how I add an item to the array:

```
 @IBAction func addBarber(_ sender: Any) {
        let newCompany = Company(owner: "String", image: UIImage(named: "insta")!, type: "Barber")
        barbers.append(newCompany)
```

So how can I check when the barber array changes that the cells in the collectionview changes as well

Comment: You don't need a listener, you know exactly when an item was added. At the end of  `addBarber` reload the collection view or – better – insert a cell animated.

Comment: @vadian thank you that worked! Didn't know you could do that hahah